# Selecting a specific cell while working within a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

My code is doing various operations (copy/pasting etc.) within a range and I need to be within the range and perform a calculation within one of the cell (eg: row 1 , column 6 of range)

```
Dim cols as long, rng as range
rng = range ("A1:H12")
cols = 15

With rng.Offset(0, cols).Select
 "Some other code in between".....
 .Range(.Cells(1, 6), .Cells(1, 6)).Value = 6 * 2 ' intend to perform a calculation in the cell within the selected range

End with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Range().Cells()
This returns a Range Object or cell using indexes relative to that range, using the first index as the row number inside the range and the second one as the column number.

So, in theory you should be able to use functions (or methods) of the range object retrieved using .Cells()

I guess you could use the *Offset* function on a Range gotten using Cells as well.

In that range you have, that is 
*A1:H12*

```
Dim cols as long, rng as range
rng = range ("A1:H12")
cols = 15

With rng.Offset(0, cols).Select
 "Some other code in between".....
 .Cells(1, 6).Value = 6 * 2 ' Performs calculation in the 1st row and 6th column in the first row and sixth column inside A1:H12.
'The result would be the Cell F1

End with
```

If you had:

```
Set R = Range("A5:C10")
R.Cells(2,3)
```

Would give you cell C6 cell.

Using the Offset function:

```
Range("A1:H12").Cells(1, 6).Offset(4,2)
```

This would take F1 cell and then move 4 rows downwards and 2 columns to the right. So, after testing it on the console it returns *H5*

Comment: Could I refer to some other cell using the offset function>? e.g .Cells(1, 6).Value = .Cells (offset(1,-10) ?

Comment: @Yusuf I'd have to try it. But as you wrote it would not work. I'll update the answer, but .Cell returns a Range so doing .RAnge.Offset() should work